# How to arrange the amount in words as same as Total number?

Tags: php, jquery

When I entered some objects in Item  then automatically others  values filled after fetching from database. and from **Base Total** to **Amount in words** are also calculated through database. and when I give the some number of value to **Round Of** below **total** will be changed. But my problem is after changed the **Total** There was didn't changed the **Amount in words** value.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ClP.png)

```
Round Of<input type="text" class="form-control inv_all_total_round"  id ="inv_all_total_round" value="<?php  if(isset($invoicedata)){ echo $invoicedata->inv_all_total_round_of; } ?> " name="inv_all_total_round_of">

Total  <input type="text" class="form-control total_balance"  id ="inv_all_total" total="<?php if(isset($invoicedata)){ echo round($invoicedata->inv_all_total); } ?>" value="" name="inv_all_total" readonly>

Amount in words  <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="inv_amt_inwords" value="<?php if(isset($invoicedata)){ echo $invoicedata->inv_amt_inwords; } ?>" name="inv_amt_inwords" readonly>
```

And This is the Jquery code

```
alll_tot = $("#inv_all_total").attr("total");
$("#inv_all_total").val(alll_tot);

round_offf = $("#inv_all_total_round").val();

$( "#inv_all_total_round" ).keyup(function() {
    round_offf = $("#inv_all_total_round").val();
    alll_tot   = $("#inv_all_total").attr("total");
    var final_tot = parseFloat(alll_tot) + parseFloat(round_offf);
    if(round_offf!=''){
        if(isNaN(final_tot)==false){
            $("#inv_all_total").val(final_tot);
        }
    }else{
        $("#inv_all_total").val(alll_tot);
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont know what you mean by _arrange the amount in words as same as Total number_ Can you show us an example of what you want to see in that field

Comment: Sir pls click the example then see the image of my output...

Comment: I already have, still dont know what you are trying to change

Comment: When I Change the Round of value There will be need to change as same as Amount in words value....I mean number = words(13000 = Thirteen Thousand).

Comment: Yes, so where do those words get created? In javascript or PHP

Comment: I wrote code in Javascript Jquery sir...

Comment: So call the function again when you round the number

Comment: That was didn't work properly...